# How to redirect to a route in a called function laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am tidying up my code and it makes sense for me to remove the login function outside of my formhandler function.  However, when I call the return route line in my called function, it simply returns this route back to the parent controller, which does nothing with it.  I want my redirect to be carried out within the called function.

```
public static function loginFormHandler(){

 //some stuff is done

$this->doLogin();
}

public static function doLogin(){

if (\Auth::attempt($this->credentials, $this->remember)) {
         return \Redirect::route("dashboard");
    }

}
```

It is not redirecting but coming back to `loginFormHandler` , which I know because it's not going to the dashboard page.

Comment: The problem don't seem to be the redirection to the route, but the authentication. Can you paste the code where you verify if the user is logged and redirect to loginFormHandler?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible.  When you say `return Redirect::route('dashboard')`, its returning that function call to the calling function, rather than carrying out the function.  By leaving off return, it still comes back to the calling function anyway.

I have since reorganised my logic.

Answer (score 3):

You have to return what is returned from the method call.  The first function should look something like this:

```
public static function loginFormHandler(){

    //some stuff is done

    return $this->doLogin();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But, you can redirect to URL:

```
Redirect::to('/dashboard');
```

and that is a route:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
```

Goodluck

Comment: it still errors as it is coming back to the called function instead of siimply going to the dashboard page.  I know this because it has gone into the layout view and is expecting a variable.  There is no variable, because the `loginformhandler` doesn't pass any.

Answer (score 0):

I like to keep my redirects anchored to the controllers, in order to have the possibility to change SEO strategy if needed. To achieve this is really simple:

```
return Redirect::action('SomeController@someFunction');
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Hello i am building an Lumen API right now and i needed the same functionality to return response from other function.

I hope this could help.

```
//helpers.php
function responseWithJsonErrorsArray($text, $code)
    return response('error' => $text, $code);

//FooTrait.php
protected function fooBar(){
   responseWithJsonError('Foo Error', 404)->send();
   exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return what is being returned in your function , like :

```
public static function loginFormHandler(){

    //some stuff is done

    return $this->doLogin();
}

 public static function doLogin(){

 if (\Auth::attempt($this->credentials, $this->remember)) {
     return \Redirect::route("dashboard");
 }
```

}

Answer (score -2):

> Look in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects)

You can use:

```
return redirect('home/dashboard');
return redirect()->route('profile', ['id' => 1]);
return redirect()->action('HomeController@index');
return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', 'Profile updated!');
...
```